# active record search in a range, but outer way around

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, range

noob here.

i am asking for an way to search in an range, that gets all records, that is not in the range.

example of the normal way:

```
Customer.where(body_size: 160..210)
```

how i want it:

```
Customer.where(body_size: !160..210)
```

so, i get all records that is lower than 160 and bigger than 210. Dos provided rails something like the code above?

Basically i want something like this:

```
Customer.where("body_size < ? AND body_size > ?", 160, 210)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `where.not`:

```
Customer.where.not(body_size: 160..210)
```

This translates to the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM customers  WHERE (NOT (body_size BETWEEN 160 AND 200))
```

Comment: Thx mate, even i read the guide, i totally forgot the 'not' call.